# Spellthieves and stolen spells reserve

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic

Kind of related to [my other spellthief question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120800).

In the Steal spell description, it is mentionned "At any one time, a spellthief can possess a maximum number of stolen spells equal to his class level" and "Alternatively, a spellthief of 4th level or higher can use the stolen spell power to cast any spellthied spell that he knows of the same level or lower"

Assuming a 20th level spellthief that stole four 5th level spell for simplicity's sake, and they all are Cone of cold. If the spellthief would want to cast a 3rd level spellthief spell, say Globe of invisibility,  what would happen to his "spell power reserve" ?

I can see two options :

1. he's left with 3 cone of cold and 2 levels of spells that can only be used to fuel his own spells

   or
2. he's left with 3 cone of cold and that's it

Which should be the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

Choice 2 is the official rule. The phrase “of the same spell level or lower” is referring to the spell as a unit, not simply as a reservoir of spell levels. Powering a 3rd-level spell with a 5th-level stolen spell’s power works (5th is sufficient), but wasteful (5th is greater than necessary).

However, given spellthief is a weak class (and it is), seeking simple ways to make them a little more flexible is a good idea: allowing stolen spells to be broken down into constituent levels to power spellthief spells is a great idea. I haven’t thought of that before, but I think I shall be adding it to my spellthief houserules from now on (along with giving all spellthieves the benefits of the trickster variant for free and eliminating the limit on how much stolen spell energy they can hold).

Comment: could you enlighten me as to what is the trickster variant?

Comment: @Mouhgouda *Dragon* vol. 353 includes the trickster variant on the spellthief, which sacrifices most of the spellthief’s “rogue-like features,” like trapfinding, all sneak attack improvements beyond the original 1d6, and two skill points per level, in exchange for improving the native spellthief spellcasting to use the bard’s spells per day and spells known, as well as adding the bard spell list to the trickster’s. I generally allow all spellthieves to be tricksters, but without losing their “rogue-like” features. It makes them more like a bard who has spell stealing instead of music.

Comment: oh nice... not a bad suggestion. talking about dragon magazines and stuff.... is there an archive where you can, like.... access them or something? adding stuff in the game without clear reference material is ground for ..... lets state it as "Abuse"

Comment: @Mouhgouda No repository like that is offered by Wizards of the Coast (they don’t support 3.5e anymore) or by Paizo Publishing (who published *Dragon* at the time, but now is focused solely on their own Pathfinder spin-off). I doubt anyone else would ever have the legal right to offer such a repository. A gaming group I’m in just happens to have a pretty complete collection, so I have access to them that way.

Comment: Meh... they should've made them public.... there seems to be some pretty nice stuff in there nobody'll ever know.

Comment: @Mouhgouda Unfortunately, neither of them want their new material to have to compete with their old material if they can help it. In reality, they actually do have to compete with their own old material quite a bit (i.e. they have to convince people who have the old material that the new material is worth buying even though those people already have the old material and don’t have to buy it), but they’re both interested in limiting that as much as possible. Sadly, that’s business. And money’s tight enough in this industry that I have a hard time blaming them.